# Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused)

Tags: intellij-idea, derby

I am trying to connect to a database in my intellij program but keep getting the following error:

Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused)

I'm assuming it's some issue with the Derby install, but cannot figure out what the exact problem is.

Comment: You need to start your Derby Network Server. It is not automatically started, unless you have taken some special measures to cause that. Typically, you start the server explicitly, then run your program which connects to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem when I was using a hostname other than localhost. I discovered that the default setting for the network server will only allow connections on  the "localhost" address.

To change this set this property in derby.properties

> derby.drda.host=0.0.0.0

which should allow connections from any host.
I can now connect using the hostname of the machine, even though I am on the same machine.

If this is not your issue, have you ensured that there is a firewall rule configured?

Comment: After looking into the issue more, it turns out there was an underlying firewall issue